# Unable to click on a <a> tag- selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, click, newrelic

While trying to click on a link using Newrelic synthetic monitor(selenium based), it appears to have started failing since few days. The screenshot of error shows the control hovered over the link but didnt click.

```
.then(function() {
  log(10, 'clickElement "Dashboard"');
  return $browser.waitForAndFindElement(By.xpath('//*[contains(text()," Dashboard ")]'), DefaultTimeout); })
.then(function (el) { el.click();  })
```

Element:

```
<a _ngcontent-avd-c527="" cdkmonitorelementfocus="" rel="noopener noreferrer" queryparamshandling="merge" class="name trimmedTextWithEllipsis ng-star-inserted" href="**" target="_self" pbi-focus-tracker-idx="17"> Dashboard <!----><!----><!----><!----></a>
```

Comment: What error are you getting ? Have you tried with other locator ? like `CSS` or `ClassName`, also try `//*[normalize-space()=' Dashboard ']`

Comment: also try `//a[contains( ...blah` and not `//*[contains( ...blah`  - the latter is a wildcard that might match a span or a div. the `//a` will ensure you're matching the  right element

Answer (score 1):

My "favourite" automation issues. You can try:

1. Check if the HTML has changed (new iframe or another anchor element that receives the click instead).
2. Click more than once. Try double click.
3. Try another type of click using the Actions class
   https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/mouse/
4. Try to debug and if it is not reproducible in debug, it may be timing issue so you can try to wait a bit more.